# How to query a single document from a Mongodb collection with react

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I'm trying to build a search bar with a react frontend and node backend, that will let me search a customer ID from a mongoDB collection, then pull all of the data from a single document down from within the collection and display it on my react app.

Currently, I am just trying to get to get the single document bit to work, if this is possible. At the moment, it pulls down the entire collection.

My current Node code:

Search router

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const tfiPaintCodesRouter = express.Router();

const PaintInfoSchema = require('../models/PaintInfoSchema.js');

tfiPaintCodesRouter.route('/get').get(function (req, res) {
  const tfipaintcode = new PaintInfoSchema(req.body);
  console.log(req.body)
  tfipaintcode.save()
    .then(tfipaintcode => {
        res.json('Got data!!');
    })
    .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).send("unable to get data");
    console.log('CustomerID is required', err.res);
    });
});

tfiPaintCodesRouter.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    PaintInfoSchema.find(function (err, tfipaintcodes){
    if(err){
      console.log('this is an error!', err.res);
    }
    else {
      res.json(tfipaintcodes);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = tfiPaintCodesRouter;
```

Mongo schema using mongoose.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  // Create schema
 const PaintInfoSchema =  new Schema({
        customerID: {
            required: true,
            index: true,
            unique: true,
            type: String
        },
        companyName: {
            index: true,
            type: String
        },
        curtainCodes: {
            index: true,
            type: String
        },
        sinageCodes: {
            index: true,
            type: String
        },
        Notes: {
            index: true,
            type: String
        },
        Method: {
            index: true,
            type: String
        },
    },{
      collection: 'tfiPaintCodes'
    });
PaintInfoSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
module.exports = mongoose.model('PaintInfoSchema', PaintInfoSchema)
```

My current react code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {  Form, FormGroup, Input, Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import './Search.css'
import axios from 'axios'

class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
          searchInfo: []
    };  
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { value } = event.target;
    console.log('Value', value)
    this.setState({
      query: value
    });

    this.search(value);

  };

  search = query => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getData')
       .then(res =>{
        const searchInfo = (res.data || []).map(obj => ({ 
          company: obj.companyName,
          sinage: obj.sinageCodes,
          method: obj.Method,
          notes: obj.Notes}));


          this.setState({ searchInfo });
       })
    };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.search("");
  }

    render() {
        return(
            <Container>
                 <Form>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={{ size: 6 ,offset: 3}}>
                            <FormGroup className="SearchBar">
                              <Input onChange={this.handleInputChange} type="search" name="search" id="exampleSearch" placeholder="search" />
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>

                </Form>
       <ul>
        {this.state.searchInfo.map(function(searchInfo, index){
          return (
              <div key={index}>
                <h1>NAME: {searchInfo.company}</h1>
                <p>{searchInfo.sinage}</p>
                <p>{searchInfo.method}</p>
                <p>{searchInfo.notes}</p>
              </div>
            )
          }
        )}
      </ul>
            </Container>
        );
      }
    }
export default Search
```

The code above queries mongodb, then pulls down all of the data stored in my collection, here is an image of the returned data.

Data displayed in frontend

[image]

But i want to know if it is possible to just pull down one document in that collection, so it would just display one Name: and then the other 4 bits of data.

I have the data stored in Mlab, here is a screenshot of the documents stored in my collection.

data in mongodb
[image]

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: You can get only one object from response using res.data[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to pull only one document from the DB (if you don't need more in your case).

Mongoose, as any other ORM/ODM, gives you those options:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

With `FindOne` you can search for documents but get only one (aka. "the first found") document back.
If you need a fixed number of returned documents, you can use `limit(10)` to, for example, return only 10 documents.

Though it appears to me that your code-snippets don't show the exact segment where do the query in Mongoose, otherwise we could have shown you what to do in your own example.

Comment: Awesome thanks mate! That is what I am looking for :D